# How do I prevent my Google Map from resetting when parent component's state is updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-state

I need to prevent my Google Map from reverting to its original center and zoom settings every time its parent component re-renders.

I have a parent component that contains two main child components: a Google Map and a sidebar. On the screen it looks like this:

[image]

My intention is to populate the sidebar with information when a particular marker is clicked. Here's the code:

**PARENT:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import MapComponent from "../Components/Map2";

export default function ACA() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

  const FlexContainer = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
    width: "98vw",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 4,
    [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
      flexDirection: "column",
    },
  }));

  const updateSidebar = (elec) => {
    setInfo(elec);
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        minHeight: "100vh",
        minWidth: "100vw",
        background: "linear-gradient(to bottom, black, midnightblue)",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center",
        paddingTop: 10,
      }}
    >
      <FlexContainer>
        <MapComponent updateSidebar={updateSidebar} />
        <div
          style={{
            height: "650px",
            maxHeight: "80vh",
            width: "650px",
            maxWidth: "98vw",
            border: "2px solid black",
            backgroundColor: "whitesmoke",
            borderRadius: 8,
          }}
        >
          <h4>{info}</h4>
        </div>
      </FlexContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**MAPCOMPONENT**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { APIProvider, Map, AdvancedMarker } from "@vis.gl/react-google-maps";
import Axios from "axios";

export default function MapComponent({ updateSidebar }) {
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getElectorates = async () => {
      try {
        const elecs = await Axios.get("http://localhost:3930/admin/getMapData");
        setMarkers(elecs.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };

    getElectorates();
  }, []);

  return (
    <APIProvider apiKey="<redacted>">
      <Map
        style={{
          width: "650px",
          height: "650px",
          maxWidth: "80vw",
          maxHeight: "80vh",
        }}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: -23.698, lng: 133.8807 }}
        defaultZoom={4}
        gestureHandling={"greedy"}
        disableDefaultUI={true}
        mapId="<redacted>"
      >
        {markers.map((el, i) => {
          return (
            <AdvancedMarker
              position={el.coords}
              key={i}
              onClick={() => {
                updateSidebar(el.electorate);
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Map>
    </APIProvider>
  );
}
```

The issue is that whenever I click on a marker and execute the updateSidebar function, the parent component's state is updated which in turn causes the map to revert to its original center and zoom settings. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I would suggest restructuring your code a little. Here because the parent's state is updated, it will for sure, rerender both parent and children components. Maybe use global state management? So you have states in the sidebar, and have the global state updater inside of the map `updateSidebar` function. This way, your parent component won't need to store any state and won't cause it to rerender.

Comment: Or, I'm not entirely sure about this `Map` component, I see that you have `defaultZoom` and `defaultCenter`, maybe you can make these `zoom` and `center` values controlled? So that even if it rerenders, it won't reset to its default values? UPDATE: From here https://visgl.github.io/react-google-maps/docs/api-reference/components/map they do have `zoom` and `center` as its props, so you can make them controlled with a `useState`

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your MapComponent. with React.memo ? checkout this link for more understanding https://refine.dev/blog/react-memo-guide/#investigation

Answer (score 0):

### You should define your `FlexContainer` component outside your **parent component**

There's nothing wrong with your implementation of the `MapComponent`. But from what I can see from your code, you have defined `FlexContainer` within your main component `ACA` like so:

```
export default function ACA() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

  const FlexContainer = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
    width: "98vw",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 4,
    [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
      flexDirection: "column",
    },
  }));
  //....The rest of the code
```

Wherein you also returned it within the `ACA` component:

```
return (
  <div
    style={{
      minHeight: "100vh",
      minWidth: "100vw",
      background: "linear-gradient(to bottom, black, midnightblue)",
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      alignItems: "center",
      paddingTop: 10,
    }}
  >
    <FlexContainer>
      <MapComponent updateSidebar={updateSidebar} />
      <div
        style={{
          height: "650px",
          maxHeight: "80vh",
          width: "650px",
          maxWidth: "98vw",
          border: "2px solid black",
          backgroundColor: "whitesmoke",
          borderRadius: 8,
        }}
      >
        <h4>{info}</h4>
      </div>
    </FlexContainer>
  </div>
);
```

This causes your `FlexContainer` to be redefined everytime the main component gets rerendered. Because of it, everything else inside it gets redefined and rebuilt also. That's why your `MapComponent` resets to its original state.

To fix this, you must define `FlexContainer` outside of your main/parent component `ACA`. In this way, your FlexContainer is already defined regardless of how many times your parent component rerenders. Then this would not also cause your `MapComponent` to be rebuilt from scratch.

With that said, your parent component's code should look something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import MapComponent from "../Components/Map2";

export default function ACA() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

  // Removed the FlexContainer definition here, and moved it outside
  // this component.

  const updateSidebar = (elec) => {
    setInfo(elec);
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        minHeight: "100vh",
        minWidth: "100vw",
        background: "linear-gradient(to bottom, black, midnightblue)",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center",
        paddingTop: 10,
      }}
    >
      <FlexContainer>
        <MapComponent updateSidebar={updateSidebar} />
        <div
          style={{
            height: "650px",
            maxHeight: "80vh",
            width: "650px",
            maxWidth: "98vw",
            border: "2px solid black",
            backgroundColor: "whitesmoke",
            borderRadius: 8,
          }}
        >
          <h4>{info}</h4>
        </div>
      </FlexContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

// Move the FlexContainer component definition here
const FlexContainer = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
    width: "98vw",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 4,
    [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
      flexDirection: "column",
    },
  }));
```

Then this should fix your issue.

Here's a [proof of concept codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/amazing-turing-mjlwfg?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu6j0g7n00063b6iku21fdm8%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu6j0g7n00023b6i3btk8np5%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu6j0g7n00033b6im9vrbcfu%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu6j0g7n00053b6i2pd3qfrr%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B55.978156735006706%252C44.021843264993294%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clu6j0g7n00023b6i3btk8np5%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu6j0g7n00023b6i3btk8np5%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu6kfej600023b6ip6pqbora%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A13%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A22%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A13%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A22%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FMapComponent.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu6kfej600023b6ip6pqbora%2522%257D%252C%2522clu6j0g7n00053b6i2pd3qfrr%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu6j0g7n00053b6i2pd3qfrr%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu6n8vfa00cv3b6hh9ekf4ul%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu6n8vfa00cv3b6hh9ekf4ul%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clu6j0g7n00033b6im9vrbcfu%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu6j0g7n00033b6im9vrbcfu%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) that you can try and test out yourself.

> NOTE: I made a sample `ContainerDiv` in replacement to your `FlexContainer`. But it still proves the point of this answer.